# R: get the best N values of all list subsets

Tags: r, list, extract

I have the summaries of many linear models in a list called "listlmsummary".

```
listlmsummary <- lapply(listlm, summary)
listlmsummary
```

The output of `listlmsummary` looks like this (quite shortened):

```
$a
Residual standard error: 3835 on 1921 degrees of freedom
  (50 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:   0.11, Adjusted R-squared:  0.1063 
F-statistic: 29.68 on 8 and 1921 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

$b
Residual standard error: 3843 on 1898 degrees of freedom
  (68 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.1125,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1065 
F-statistic: 18.51 on 13 and 1898 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

$c
Residual standard error: 3760 on 1881 degrees of freedom
  (87 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.1221,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.117 
F-statistic: 23.79 on 11 and 1881 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

$d
Residual standard error: 3826 on 1907 degrees of freedom
  (60 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.115, Adjusted R-squared:  0.1094 
F-statistic: 20.64 on 12 and 1907 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I want to extract the highest N (e.g. 2) Adjusted R-squared values to find the best model, and that it also tells me what list element this Adj.R-sqr value comes from. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

I know that I can get a single R-squared value with this call:

```
listlmsummary[["a"]]$adj.r.squared
```

But extracting all R-squared values with something like this `listlmsummary[[]]$adj.r.squared` or `listlmsummary[[c("a", "b", "c", "d")]]$adj.r.squared`and then ordering the output does not work.

Thank you for any help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sapply(listlmsummary, function(x) x$adj.r.squared)
```

Also see the new `broom` package.

Comment: That one's nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

We can use `sapply` to extrat the `adj.r.squared` into a `vector` and `order` in decreasingly.  Then get the `head` of 'n' elements from the ordered 'listlmsummary'

```
i1 <- order(-sapply(listlmsummary, `[[`, "adj.r.squared"))
head(listlmsummary[i1], n)
```

NOTE: This was answered with the logic and the complete solution requested by the user

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. However, it says `Error in lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : Object 'adj.r.squared' not found`. Do you know why it can't find the adf.r.squared values?

Comment: @fabha  The `adj.r.squared` need to be in quotes i.e. `"adj.r.squared"`.  Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way to do  it might be:

```
Maxr2sq <- max(unlist(sapply (listlm, "[", i = "adj.r.squared")))
Position <- which(unlist(sapply (listlm, "[", i = "adj.r.squared")) == Maxr2sq)
Maxr2sq
Position
```

However, you might benefit of storing all the results in a data.frame for future reference. For instance, it is theoretically possible that more than one Adj.R2 get the same value. Additionally, it is convenient to store the regression's Call (i.e. formula).

In that case, you could run:

```
library(tidyverse)

AR2 <- sapply (listlm, "[", i = "adj.r.squared") %>%
       stack() %>% 
       select(values) %>% 
       rename(Adj.R.sqr = values)
Call <- as.character(sapply (listlm, "[", i = "call"))
Position <- setNames(data.frame(seq(1:length(listlm))), c("Position"))
DF <- as_data_frame(cbind(AR2,Call,Position))
DF
```

Comment: Ha, that just got me further than I anything! Thanks a ton! :)